# vue-truncate-filter not filtering and throwing error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, truncate

I am not able to use the [vue-truncate-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-truncate-filter) npm package. I Installed it using the command line with this command:

```
npm install vue-truncate-filter --save
```

However I am seeing the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: truncate 30 '....'

Here is my template:

```
<div v-show="wbwState[index]" v-bind:style="{ margin:`0 ${8}px ${8}px ${8}px`, color: '#C10E40' }">{{ word.english | truncate 5 '....' }}</div>
```

and:

```
<div class="eng">{{ word.english | truncate 5 '....' }}</div>
```

In main.js I have:

```
const VueTruncate = require('vue-truncate-filter');
Vue.use(VueTruncate)
```

I also tried using `Vue.use()` in the actual component itself. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vue 2, this [filter should be used like this](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-truncate-filter#vue-2x):

```
{{ text | truncate(100) }}
```

So your code should be

```
<div class="eng">{{ word.english | truncate(5) }}</div>
```

Here is a [working example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KomjoBYV1NIQJxJc_B0).